# How to play Fade and Slide transition together on the same views?

Tags: android, kotlin, slide, fade, android-transitions

I work with `Android Transition API` and I got this 'bug' - when I start my `TransitionSet` with only `Slide's` transitions all work fine, but if I add `Fade` transition for whole view my `Slide's` doesn't work and I see only `Fade` animation.

**How to play Fade and Slide transition together?** And why my `Slide` not working with `Fade` transition?

This is my code:

```
val startTransition = TransitionSet()
    startTransition.startDelay = 600L
    startTransition.duration = 3000L

    startTransition.addTransition(Slide(Gravity.START).addTarget(R.id.ivMenu))
    val slide = Slide(Gravity.END)
            .addTarget(R.id.ivSearch)
            .addTarget(R.id.ivOptionMenu)
    startTransition.addTransition(slide)

    startTransition.addTransition(Fade()) // without this line slides work
    startTransition.ordering = TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER // I set it!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrap `Slide` and `Fade` transitions into `TransitionSet`, add target to this `TransitionSet` and it help me.

**Demo code**:

```
TransitionSet().apply {
    addTransition(Fade())
    addTransition(Slide())

    addTarget(R.id.targetId)
}
```